# Does using ECC DRAM memory require a certain CPU? why?

Tags: memory

ECC DRAM, helps to avoid bit flips (i.e. induced by cosmic ray etc.) which else would go undedected. That is great and I instantly wanted to order some of it, to replace my non ECC. But....

... it seems to me that is not so easy, indeed I would need a board + CPU that supports it, right?

If so I wonder why. The (n-level) parity bit checking would require more memory as can be effectively used on a memory module (for the redudancy allowing the ECC checks), yet one might think that the module, having all the information, could by itself do the ECC error correcting?

Where is the role the CPU would play there?

- if the error is correctable then it should be transparently corrected by the module, right?
- only if the error is dedected but not correctable I would see some reason to interact with the CPU, as to flag/inform/notice that an error has occured.

Comment: You kinda answered yourself with the second bullet point, at least partially.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen true, but still I hope for a more informed answer, which would explain this to me a bit better. For instance the changes for bit errors are real, but not really that high. If the DRAM memory would be able to do the first, and by this even correct simple errors, it would already greatly reduce bit errors, even without need to involve the CPU.

Comment: You do need a motherboard that supports ECC ram.

Comment: Besides the [hold] flag, an very satisfactory answer was anyway possible and done by @Hennes. Proofing effectivly that the question was answerable. It would henceforth be a nice act, if those who flagged the question as "unclear" would (1) read the answer and (2) consider the need to flag the question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yet one might think that the module, having all the information, 
>   could by itself do the ECC error correcting?

In theory yes, it could.

> Where is the role the CPU would play there?

For the CPU core itself: None.

However this is usually done on the memory controller, and on modern CPU's the memory controller is part of the CPU die. So for all practical purposed you now need an ECC capable CPU.

> only if the error is dedected but not correctable I would see some reason
>   to interact with the CPU, as to flag/inform/notice that an error has
>   occured.

This does happen. It raises a [MCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception) when it detects uncorrectable read errors.

Comment: by your clear and concise answer you helped much understanding the question I raised. Indeed for doing so you provided some advanced knowlegde/insight not so readily available to me and made this question work. thank you for the response.